# Exterior angle of two line segments

Tags: geometry

Say I have a $L_1$ with end points $(0,0)$,$(1,1)$ and $L_2$ with the start point $(1,1)$ 
and the end point anywhere on the Cartesian plane. See example image below.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV6zS.jpg)

How do I determine the angle $X$ when the end point of $L_2$ can be anywhere in the Cartesian plane?

Thanks

geometry

Answer (score 1):

The slope of $L_1$ is
$$m_1=\frac{1-0}{1-0}=1$$
Let the other end point of $L_2$ be $(x,y)$.

The slope of $L_2$ then will be
$$m_2=\frac{y-1}{x-1}$$

Now, to find the angle $\theta$ between two lines with slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$, use the relation,
$$\tan\theta=\frac{m_2-m_1}{1+m_1m_2}$$

There are two angles between a pair of line segments, and it depends on the context which one you are looking for.

In this context, the angle $X$ is the angle made by $L_2$ with respect to $L_1$ when measured clockwise, while as per convention, $\theta$ is taken anti clockwise.

Thus, the relation between $X$ and $\theta$ will be,
$$X=\pi-\theta$$

Comment: Thanks @GoodDeeds, if L2  end point is at  (2,4) this gives the answer of 26 degrees, but the answer is 180 - 26 ? If the end point of L2 is at an arbitrary position is there a generic formula for the angle ? (if that make sense). Thanks once again

Comment: @tosspot Updated my answer.